# Is it possible to install Cabal package locally à la npm?

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, cabal

In npm, dependencies are installed in a directory `node_modules` relative to the directory of the dependent package. Each package stores its dependencies inside itself.

With Cabal, however, installing a package always installs it globally (i.e. in `~/.cabal`), which is a perfect recipe for nightmares and tears because different versions of packages get to conflict with eachother and everything will fail and go wrong.

I would like to install Cabal packages *locally*, i.e. in *a subdirectory of my own package*, rather than globally. All the dependencies of these packages would do the same. An example of the directory tree of my package could look like this:

```
my_package/
  dependencies/
    json/
      dependencies/
        foo/
          etc...
        bar/
          etc...
    mtl/
      etc...
  my_package.cabal
  src/
    Main.hs
```

Is this possible to do, and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: With newer versions of cabal, you should use [cabal sandboxes](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html), which are now built-in, rather than cabal-dev.

Take a look at the [`cabal-dev`](http://corp.galois.com/blog/2010/12/20/cabal-dev-sandboxed-development-builds-for-haskell.html) tool. It's similar to `virtualenv` for Python.

Basically, where you would use the command `cabal`, use `cabal-dev`. So to install the package you're working on, go that directory and do `cabal-dev install`. You can also run `ghc-pkg` through `cabal-dev`, so you can do something like `cabal-dev ghc-pkg unregister foo-bar`. Also, you can start `GHCi` with it too: `cabal-dev ghci`.

By default, `cabal-dev` installs packages into a `cabal-dev` directory inside your project--this is what you call `dependencies` in your example.

Comment: Installing cabal-dev yields version conflicts. How ironic. T_T

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov That worked, though I had to `--force-reinstall` the template-haskell package. I hope it didn't break anything.

Comment: Reinstalling template-haskell is usually *very* bad. It comes with GHC and should only be updated by installing a new version of GHC.

Comment: @Carl kinda difficult if I already have the latest version of GHC.

Comment: My point was that reinstalling it is always wrong. Sometimes it's just a waste of time, much more often than not it breaks everything that uses it. But "waste of time" is the best case. If something is telling you to upgrade it, the problem is elsewhere.